# To get list of member from list of objects using Streams java

Tags: java, list, object, java-stream

I have a class with two members and a list of objects of that class . Now I want to extract list of members from the list of objects.

e.g :

```
class student {
      int Id;
      String studentName;
}
```

now I need to retrieve a list of studentName, from list of students. How can this be done with java8 Streams?

Solution without using streams:

```
List<student> studentList;
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator iterator = studentList.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
  nameList.add(iterator.next().getStudentName());
}
```

Comment: Did you try it first without using `Streams`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: yes . By using list iterator and running a loop.

Answer (score 17):

You need to use [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method, something like this:

```
List<Student> students = ...;
List<String> names = students.stream().map(Student::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thanks . it worked

Comment: @user3425563, remember to accept and up-vote one of the answers, if you find it useful.